# How do I fix my faulty HTML form with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've set up a dual form layout, one next to the other, and essentially I'm trying to have the input data from the first form end up in the fields for the second form. Both forms are on the same page and ideally the second form would store the data when it's received, even if the page is reloaded.

I thought I had the first part worked out; where the data would send when the "Send" button is pressed, but it seems I've gone wrong somewhere.

Any clarification on my error(s) would be appreciated.

I've thus far tried to use a JavaScript function with GetElementById to send my inputs.

Below is a sample of my issue:

My goal is to use the "Send" button from form1 to display inputs in the fields of form2, ideally with said data remaining after closing and reentering the page.

```js
function sendData(f1) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = f1.name.value;
}
```

```css
.left {
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  padding: 60px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <form name="form1">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>SEND DATA</legend>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="20px" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Student Name</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="button" value="SEND" onclick="sendData('form1')"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>RECEIVE DATA</legend>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="20px">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Student Name</label></td>
          <td><label id="name"></label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: _"ideally with said data remaining after closing and reentering the page."_ This will only happen with some sort of storage like cookies or re-population via a database.

Comment: You're passing a string value to `sendData()`. A string does not have the property "value". And above comment is right. If you want data to persist after a reload youll have to store it somewhere like a db or localstorage in the browser.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine, Okay, thank you. I'll keep that in mind going forward.

Comment: @j08691, Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="SEND" onclick="sendData('form1')">
```

Here you're calling the **sendData** function with form1 passed as a string.

```
function sendData(f1) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = f1.name.value;
}
```

Inside the sendData function however you're trying to treat the received string as a variable.

The fix is simple though.

```
<input type="button" value="SEND" onclick="sendData(form1)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending your form1 as string in sendData function. Instead send it without quotes.

Or You can give your text field an id and retrieve data using that id.

```js
function sendData(f1) {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = f1.name.value;
}
```

```css
.left {
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  padding: 60px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <form name="form1">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>SEND DATA</legend>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="20px" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Student Name</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id= "form1Text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="button" value="SEND" onclick="sendData(form1)"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>RECEIVE DATA</legend>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="20px">
        <tr>
          <td><label>Student Name</label></td>
          <td><label id="name"></label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```